# Need help to identify a piece - green, like a 1x2 plate with 4 angled cubes hanging off at odd angles

Tags: part-identification

Can you please help me to identify this?

I have no idea what to do with it. [image: green piece]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's a [Creeper torso](https://rebrickable.com/parts/19734/creature-torso-blocky-with-cube-feet-minecraft-creeper/) (officially 19734 Creature Torso Blocky with Cube Feet). If you're familiar with Minecraft, you'll probably recognize it once you know the context:

[image: Minecraft minifigs]

[image: Minecraft creeper from game]

Comment: every single time its one I know the answer to...someone gives a way better response than I would have.